# Learn Struts or EJB first?

Tags: java

I am an intermediate java programmer. Know how to use class, interface, enum. Know how to create GUI event-driven application. Right now I want to know about Struts, EJB, and java web programming. According to your experience, which skill should I focused first? And what requirement do I need to have to smooth my study on that skill?

ps. I am undergraduate student.

Comment: dude learn what ever ya like and what ever u are comfortable with. get back here if ya face any problems. :)

Comment: In the time it took you to create this question you probably could already have learned one of them.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what sort of jobs you want to end up in. EJBs are often used in large, outdated enterprises. Many more companies are using the Spring framework and its associated subprojects these days. You can get a feel for the technologies that people are hiring for by visiting [ITJobsWatch](http://www.itjobswatch.co.uk) and searching for specific terms.

I'd suggest steering clear of Struts altogether as I'm sure not many people would identify it as a technology of the future.

Comment: so insightful. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to learn something new, I suggest you try the Spring framework, as well as Hibernate.

EJB-s are normally used in big companies which like to stick to older (like they would consider - "more stable" technologies).

Struts... Frankly, Struts is not all that much of a big deal (if you ask me). You can do the same things (if not even better) using Spring MVC, Spring Web, Spring Webflow, etc.

It really only depends on what ***you*** would like to learn.